# Issues with Steam on 16.04

Tags: wine, games, steam

So I tried out running the .exe Steam through wine, which wasn't as smooth as I would've liked, so I uninstalled it, but it's still appearing in my apps drawer, along with all of my games. Is there any way I can get rid of these? Not only this, but when I tried using the .deb Steam, it doesn't open. It shows that it's running in task manager, but for some reason, it doesn't actually run.

Edit: Just went to uninstall and reinstall the .deb, and it's not even showing up in my installed programs, despite showing up in my apps drawer

Comment: how  you uninstalled ?

Comment: I went into terminal and typed `wine uninstaller`, which then opened a program to uninstall programs. I uninstalled Steam, but it still shows up as if it's there

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove the bottle for your used,open a terminal and type `rm -rf ~/.wine`

Comment: I for some reason don't have a  .wine folder. Maybe I installed it wrong?

Comment: open Nautilus and in your home folder press Ctrl+H, locate the .wine folder and delete it. and if you use wine it will create .wine